# Developing an Application for File Compression

Tags: c++, file, compression, 7zip, winrar

How can I compress a file in c/c++? Since I want to devlop an application like WinZip / WinRAR.
A simpler one.

Comment: honestly, look at the source for 7zip.

Comment: I don't see a reason for a downvote.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/).

Answer (score 4):

You could give [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) a try. Implementing Huffman coding is a pretty standard assignment in many CS programs.

From Wikipedia.

> In computer science and information theory, Huffman coding is an entropy encoding algorithm used for lossless data compression. The term refers to the use of a variable-length code table for encoding a source symbol (such as a character in a file) where the variable-length code table has been derived in a particular way based on the estimated probability of occurrence for each possible value of the source symbol. It was developed by David A. Huffman while he was a Ph.D. student at MIT, and published in the 1952 paper "A Method for the Construction of Minimum-Redundancy Codes".

Answer (score 2):

Quick, simple, and easy to use ZIP compression utilities for C++:

[Zip Utils - clean, elegant, simple, C++/Win32](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/zip_utils.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [gzip](http://www.gzip.org/) and [bzip2](http://www.bzip.org/). Both of these are widely used file compression algorithms that compress better than .zip does, however both of them are usually used only to compress a single file. In order to create archives, both gzip and bzip2 rely on a separate tar application.

If you would write a single application that could manage an archive containing gzipped/bzip2ed files, like winzip, that would indeed be simpler than raw gzip/bzip2.